# How to check the EE version number via PHP?

Tags: ee2, php

I'm writing an add-on and need to check the current EE version from PHP. What is the best way to get the current ExpressionEngine version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to use the `APP_VER` constant. You can see it here with a few other version constants as well:

http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/constants.html#version-constants

This will give you the version number with decimals unlike Adrian's solution so, pick which route you'd like. For example:

```
if (APP_VER == '2.5.3')
{
   do something;
}
```

Comment: Ha, I just realized it was you who asked this question! And yes I will sleep a little smarter tonight knowing I knew something you didn't ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$this->EE->config->item('app_version')` which returns a string like `253`.

I'm not sure whether this is the most reliable way to determine the version number though, or whether it's possible to get the version number including decimals.

Comment: Your way is more reliable when you use this function in the custom add-on. Because if you use the APP_VER constant in the add-on code. If user upgrade the EE version with your add-on then they will get the error of the undefined constant.